# How to find max margin for non-separable SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am new to Machine Learning. Suppose a training set of positive (square) and negative (circle) points is given like:

[image]

Obviously there would be no nice linear separator of positive and negative points. So assume there exist a transformation for (x1,x2) points as:
`y1 = (x1-5)^2, y2 = (x2-5)^2` in (y1,y2) space. We will then map all positive points to (25,25) and all negative points to (1,1).

Now, the question is how can I find the maximum-margin separator in new space? That is, what curve in the original space transforms to the straight-line boundary in the transformed space? Using that I need to determine that should a new point be considered positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

Map all the points to the new space.  Then find the maximum-margin linear separator of those mapped points.  Algorithms for finding a maximum-largin linear separator are described in the literature on SVMs (that's exactly what you need to do to train a linear SVM).  In other words, you can map the points to the new space, then can take those mapped points and train a linear SVM on them.  That's conceptually how to do it.

In practice, nonlinear SVMs use clever tricks to do the same thing, but do it faster (using the kernel trick).

Comment: Thank you. All the points are mapped into 2 points in new space (1,1) and (25,25). The question would then be how to find the line equation (without using tools like sklearn)?

Comment: @fhm, as I said in my question, the same way you find a separating line for a linear SVM.  You do know how to do that, right?  If not, you should study linear SVMs -- that algorithm is explained in many standard places.